# How do I find the right GApps for my CM?

Tags: cyanogenmod, nook-color

I've chosen https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?ty...&device=encore
(cm-11-20160815-NIGHTLY-encore.zip)

What GApps should I download?

PS: I've tried a random one (Gapps file), and it didn't work.

Comment: You can download Gapps that support on cyanogenmod from here http://opengapps.org/ (I have installed pico version on my cm 14.1 device with basic google play and services)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need if you use chrome or Firefox as internet browser then OpenGapps will try to automatically determine your Android version.

If that fails then

1. Go to settings
2. About Phone
3. There will be - Android version or version

Select that on OpenGapps website and download the suitable package....

Hope it will be helpful....